# Combinatorial proof by demonstrating bijection

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I need to prove that $n^2 = {n \choose 2} + {n+1 \choose2}$. I have already proved this using algebra, but I am required to use both algebra and a formal combinatorial proof which demonstrates a bijection between the right and left hand sides.

If someone could show me how to get started with this proof and the general steps to take and why, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

Let $A=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. Obviously $n^2=\left|A\times A\right|$. We have $\binom{n}{2}$ ways for choosing $(a,b)\in A\times A$ with $a<b$. We have $\binom{n+1}{2}=n+\binom{n}{2}$ ways for choosing $(a,b)\in A\times A$ with $a\geq b$, hence
$$ n^2=\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n+1}{2} $$
as wanted. A visual hint for $n=4$:

[image]

There are $\binom{4}{2}$ blue squares and $\binom{5}{2}$ green squares.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: You have two boxes of numbered balls. The first box has $n$ balls numbered $1$ through $n$, and the second has $n+1$ balls numbered $0$ through $n$. You choose a box and draw two balls from it; say that they are numbered $k$ and $\ell$.

- If you drew from the first box, you write down the ordered pair $\langle\min\{k,\ell\},\max\{k,\ell\}\rangle$, the ordered pair of $k$ and $\ell$ that has the smaller one first. If $k=3$ and $\ell=1$, for instance, you write down $\langle 1,3\rangle$.
- If you drew from the second box, and neither $k$ nor $\ell$ is $0$, you write down the ordered pair $\langle\max\{k,\ell\},\min\{k,\ell\}\rangle$, the ordered pair of $k$ and $\ell$ that has the larger one first. In $k=3$ and $\ell=1$, you write down $\langle 3,1\rangle$. If one of the numbers drawn *is* $0$, you write down the ordered pair consisting of the other number twice. E.g., if $k=0$ and $\ell=3$, you write down $\langle 3,3\rangle$.

Count the outcomes in two different ways.

Answer (score 0):

Define a map
$$f:\quad[n]\times[n]\to{[n]\choose 2}\sqcup{[n+1]\choose 2}$$
as follows:

$$f(x,y):=\left\{\eqalign{\{x,y\}\in{[n]\choose 2}\qquad&(x<y)\cr
\{x,n+1\}\in{[n+1]\choose 2}\qquad&(x=y)\cr
\{x,y\}\in{[n+1]\choose 2}\qquad&(x>y)\ ,\cr}\right.$$
and convince yourself that $f$ is bijective.